# Upgrade tmux version

Tags: openshift, redhat

I am using OpenShift scallable gear with Django installed and I need to log everything from running tmux session to a file. On my local machine I am just using tmux-logging plugin but it need tmux version >1.9. 
But 1.6 is installed on server(Why so old?).

It is possible to upgrade package version in gear without sudo/root privileges?
Or how I can log to a file with tmux 1.6 with same convenience as with tmux-logging plugin? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. [this script](https://gist.github.com/ryin/3106801) to install tmux without root privileges. Replace the `$HOME` with `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` before running it (you can't write directly to `~` on OpenShift + you want your tmux to [be persistent](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#directory-variables)) and adjust the `$TMUX_VERSION` (worked for me with `$TMUX_VERSION=1.9`).

Running the script will then install tmux into `~/app-root/data/local/`.

Comment: I am getting some error with this. But one of comments from that github page suggest using sh <(wget -qO- s.minos.io/s) -x tmux-2.0 to fetch the static binary with static-get and no compiler required then. Anyway big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
sh <(wget -qO- s.minos.io/s) -x tmux-2.0
```

You can fetch  the static binary with static-get and no compiler required then, so no root privileges requeired.
Fiala´s solution looks good but it not worked for me and this is even simpler.